# Possible to provide a subscriber's language through MailChimp API?

Tags: mailchimp

Currently, I have a signup form on a PHP page, which allows a user to enter their name and email address.

When pressed, it fires an AJAX POST to the server, and the PHP script which receives the postdata takes it and uses the MailChimp PHP API to sign up the user (via listSubscribe()).

It's a multilingual site and the issue with this is that MailChimp has no idea what the user's language is when the signup is performed via an API call. This means that the user receives their MailChimp confirmation email (i.e. 'did you actually sign up for this' etc) in English, regardless of their actual language preference.

The way I've worked around this at the moment is to create separate lists for each language, subscribing the user to the appropriate list based on which language they're viewing the site in. This means that you can set the MailChimp forms default language to the language of the list.

This feels very hacky to me, is there a better way? Doing it this way means that campaigns must be set up for each language etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not spelled out very well in the documentation. The way the form auto-translate works is by detecing the language of the browser:

http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/can-you-translate-my-signup-forms-response-emails#auto

This means when you subscribe using their form submission, they detect the browser language and then send the correct confirmation email, for example. They don't use the "language" field that can be set as a form option or with the api. I verified this with tech support, over several conversations.

So how to set the language when subscribing through the api? Same way, set the browser language in the http header of the api call. This worked like a champ for me. Can't say how you would do it in your php app, but in Rails using the Gibbon gem, you would pass the values in the 'headers' option, which just sets it in the http header of the api call:

```
gibbon_api.lists.subscribe(headers: {'Accept-Language' => request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']}, all_other_params...)
```

At least this method worked for me. Hope this helps...

Comment: So no way to do this via `mailchimp.lists.batch_subscribe`; am I correct?

Comment: If you're using the V2 Mailchimp API, then I think setting the `Accept-Language` as I mention above should work, even with batch subscribe.  I just noticed there is now a V3 API, which I haven't worked with.  It's possible they now honor the `language` parameter, but you would have to test it out.

Comment: @Brett The API V3 only honors the `language` parameter in that it sets it to the subscriber, but the confirmation emails are still sent in the list's default language. Setting the `Accept-Language` header apparently works: https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/issues/148

Comment: It looks like setting `Accept-Language` header solution doesn't work anymore – can anyone confirm or deny?

Answer (score 3):

There is a "Language" field in MailChimp, but I don't see a way to access this via merge tags. Looking through one of my lists where I know each subscriber personally, MailChimp's language tool does not appear to be that reliable.

I'd create either a form field or group within MailChimp, then add a field that allows a user to specify their preferred language via a dropdown (or automatically populate this based on the content they are viewing), and use this to with merge tags to send customized content in your confirmation email. See here for [customizing the confirmation process](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-do-i-customize-each-part-of-the-confirmation-process/)

For instance, if you did this using a group to to send emails in English, French, German or Spanish using the `INTERESTED` merge tag, where English was your default language:

```
*|INTERESTED:Language:FR,DE,ES|*
 *|INTERESTED:Language:FR|*
   French content here
 *|END:INTERESTED|*
 *|INTERESTED:Language:DE|*
   German content here
 *|END:INTERESTED|*
 *|INTERESTED:Language:ES|*
   Spanish content here
 *|END:INTERESTED|*
*|ELSE|*
  English content here for everyone else, even those with an undefined language.
*|END:INTERESTED|*
```

Comment: I had no idea you could use merge tags in expressions like that. That seems like a good answer, thanks!

Comment: There is a merge tag for the language now: `MC_LANGUAGE`

Answer (score 0):

For ChimpKit3 (v3) (iOS - objective-c repo) I added subscriber language to support the auto translate option for response mails in [MailChimp](https://mailchimp.com/).

So it's just a matter of adding the 'Accept-Language' field to the request header.

https://github.com/mailchimp/ChimpKit3/pull/22

Objective-C example:

```
NSDictionary *mailChimpParams = @{@"id": MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID,
                                  @"email": @{@"email": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",emailAddress]},
                                  @"language": @"en",
                                  @"merge_vars": mergeVars};
```

---

```
[[ChimpKit sharedKit] callApiMethod:@"lists/subscribe"
                         withParams:mailChimpParams
               andCompletionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) { ...
```